# How to use avcodec_register() in C++ program

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I don't want to register all the codecs with  [avcodec_register_all();](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/allcodecs_8c.html)
I want to register one specific codec.
Strangly, I cannot find any working example that shows how to use [avcodec_register()](http://ffmpeg.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.6/libavcodec_2utils_8c_882513208349dbcea177626d9fd7ed92.html) . Most of the examples [I found](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496583/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-ffmpeg) suggest something like this:

```
extern AVCodec ff_h264_decoder;

avcodec_register(&ff_h264_decoder);
```

But I am getting

> unresolved external symbol

Error from the linker. I tried to wrap the struct with `extern "C"` , but still the same.Do I need to link h264 lib to access those structs?

Comment: Which symbol is unresolved?

Comment: @AlanStokes ff_h264_decoder

Comment: Did you link `libavcodec`?

Comment: Sure,the programs works fine with avcodec register all.

Comment: [register_all](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/allcodecs_8c_source.html#l00062) does exactly what you did and `avcodec_register(&ff_h264_decoder)` works for me in `c`. `libx264` is only used for encoding.

Comment: @aergistal but that's exactly the point of my question. I can't get avcodec_register() working in C++ program, not C. Please read my question again.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you're not linking correctly. I can compile it just fine with `g++`. It would be useful to post the build command.

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I forgot to mention that I run on MSVC 140.  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with `MSVC` and you left out the build details. However a common cause for this kind of errors is a wrong library order in static linking so check how it handles the dependencies.

Below is an example for `g++`, maybe it helps you or someone else.

```
extern "C" {
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}

extern AVCodec ff_h264_decoder;

int main() {
    avcodec_register(&ff_h264_decoder);
}
```

and

```
g++ -o register -I/ffmpeg/include/path register.cpp -L/ffmpeg/lib/path -lavcodec -lavutil -lpthread [-possibly other libs based on configuration]
```

or use `pkg-config`.

Comment: Strangely,I tried this now again,and it compiled with no linker errors.Thanks.